# Keep class active untill last class inside is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow, that needs to be clicked in order to go to the next image/video.
However, i would like to make this automatically so it wont need any user activities.

The page looks like folowing:

```
<article class="active">
    <li class="active"> Slide 1 </li>
    <li> Slide 2 </li>
    <li> Slide 3 </li>
    <li> Slide 3 </li>
</article>

<article>
    <li> Slide 1 </li>
    <li> Slide 2 </li>
    <li> Slide 3 </li>
    <li> Slide 3 </li>
</article>

<article>
    <li> Slide 1 </li>
    <li> Slide 2 </li>
    <li> Slide 3 </li>
    <li> Slide 3 </li>
</article>
```

When a article is active, you will get a "presentation" of the li that are in there. Everytime you click the next button the next li will become active. When it's active you will only see that.

What i would like to have:

Make the first article active (like showed in the code). 
Then i want for example to automatically make Slide 1 active. After 10 seconds i want Slide 2 active. And after 30 seconds i want slide 3 active.

When it reaches the end (Slide 3 in this case). I want it to go to the next article and make those slides active after a x ammount of time.

I have been searching for this for a long time now. However i can only get the Li elements to be active after a x ammount of seconds. But i want to decide for how long i can make each Li element active. This because some slides have movies that are being played. And some are just Images.

Answer (score 1):

Made fully working exable just with bolding in action with pure JavaScript:

```html
<script>

var interval = setInterval(function(){
 console.log(1);
 var active = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
 var parent = active[0].parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
 
 var foundClass = false;
 var nextSlide = false;
 
 for(var j=0; j<parent.length; j++){
  var childs = parent[j].childNodes;
  
  for(var i=0; i<childs.length; i++){
  
   if(childs[i].nodeType==1 && foundClass){
    childs[i].className = "active";
    nextSlide = true;
    break;
   }
  
   if(childs[i].nodeType==1){
    if(childs[i].getAttribute("class")=="active"){
     childs[i].className = "";
     foundClass = true;
    }
   }
  } 
 
  if(nextSlide){
   break;
  }
 }
 
 if(!nextSlide){
  clearInterval(interval);
 }
  
}, 1000);

</script>
<style>
.active { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

<article id="initShow">
    <li class="active"> Slide 1 </li>
    <li> Slide 2 </li>
    <li> Slide 3 </li>
    <li> Slide 4 </li>
</article>

<article>
    <li> Slide 5 </li>
    <li> Slide 6 </li>
    <li> Slide 7 </li>
    <li> Slide 8 </li>
</article>

<article>
    <li> Slide 9 </li>
    <li> Slide 10 </li>
    <li> Slide 11 </li>
    <li> Slide 12 </li>
</article>
```

Comment: This is indeed what i want. It's not working correctly on my website yet. However i think i will be able to figure it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something up for you

```
function autoSpin(){

    var slideShow = $("#mySlideshowOutdiv"); //set this yourself
    var slides = $(slideShow).find("li");
    var activeSlide = $(slideShow).find("li.active")

    var timer = 5000; //5 seconds
    setTimeout(function({
        nextSlide();
    }, timer)

    function nextSlide() {
        if($(activeslide).nextAll().length == 0) { //If you're at the last "li"
            setActive($(slides).eq(0))
        } else { // Else just use the next slide in line 
            setActive($(activeSlide).next("li"));
        }
    }

    function setActive(slide){
        $(slideShow).find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(slide).addClass("active");
    }

}
```